# How do I set secure flag on cookie in asp.net web api

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I need to change the HttpOnly and Secure flag on all cookies being generated by my web.api.

To do this, I added a global filter which modifies every response from my web.api. I already have code that does this in IIS using the PreSendRequestHeaders event but this doesn't work when self hosting.

The cookies I need to change are the session and forms auth cookies. The httponly flag isn't the main problem, it's the secure flag that is the problem as we do SSL offloading so it's not set to secure automatically.

I can use HttpResponseHeadersExtensions to add cookies, but I can't see anything to update existing cookies.

I want to avoid parsing the set-cookie header manually. What's the best way to achieve this?

(this needs to work in self host and in IIS, so HttpContext.Current can't be used)

Answer (score 1):

Say the cookie is set by the ApiController itself. It could be any component but say the controller does it, like so:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
{
    var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("abc", "12345");
    cookie.Path = "/";

    var response = Request.CreateResponse();
    response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });
    return response;
}
```

Again, the cookie can be any cookie including FormsAuth. But I just use a normal cookie. If you have a message handler, you can simply create a HttpOnly and secure cookie with the same key, like so:

```
public class MyHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
                                    HttpRequestMessage request,
                                          CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("abc", "12345");
        cookie.Secure = true;
        cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        cookie.Path = "/";

        response.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });

        return response;
    }
}
```

The cookie thus sent back to the client will be a secure HttpOnly cookie.